# How to add value to an address in c

Tags: c, pointers

I have a little problem... i want to initialize an address with anither address and add a value on this address 
With something like this :

```
int size = 56;
void *addr1;
void *addr2;

addresse of addr2 = address of addr1 + size
```

so addr2 is 56 bytes further than addr1
Supposing addr1 and addr2 are not NULL.
But i have no idea how to do it, do you have any idea ?
I just want to do it, to know how to manipulate and do operations on address
Thanks

Comment: `addr2 = (void*)((char*)addr1 + size);`

Comment: Only arithmetic on concrete types pointers is possible. And many undefined behaviors are connected with this (only arithmetic in the same table is legal)

Comment: Or maybe just use `char*` instead of `void*` in first place, then you can write `addr2 = addr1 + size;`.

Comment: Maybe you should [edit]  your question and tell us what you're _actually_ trying to achieve. Then you may get more accurate answers. On what kind of platform is this code supposed to run? This could be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, use `char*` pointers, when you are doing things like this. The pointer arithmetic `+` adds the right operand times `sizeof(your_pointer)` to the address.

So in case of a 64 bit architecture, the operation `addr2 = addr1 + size` would not add `56`, but `56*8 = 448`. `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1`, so nothing can go wrong, then.

Furthermore, consider `ssize_t` (or if size is guaranteed to be positive `size_t` as type for your size variable.

In your code example, however, `addr1` is uninitialized. You have to initialize it with some address, before doing your addition, otherwise the addition results in undefined behavior. The same holds for a resulting address which lies outside the memory block originally allocated for `addr1`.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, in order to avoid undefined behavior, you need to keep inside an allocated memory region. The C standard specifies that pointer arithmetic outside an allocated memory region is undefined behavior. So, let's allocate some memory:

```
void *addr1 = malloc(1000);
```

Now, C does quite a clever thing. A pointer to a memory region is basically an array. What sense would it have to access the second byte of the memory region, if each element of the array has a size of 4 bytes? Well, not much, since this will bring you right in the middle of an element.

Thus, after the following (pseudo)code is ran:

```
T *a;
a = address;
a = a + 10;
```

the value of `a` will be `address + 10 * sizeof(T)`, where T is some type. However, you can't do this with `void`, since pointer arithmetic on `void` pointers is undefined.

Thus, what you can do, is to convert `a` to `char*` (since `sizeof(char)` is 1) and simply add `size` to it:

```
a = (void*)((char*)a + size);
```

Comment: "will be address + sizeof(T)" - Don't you mean "address + 10*sizeof(T)", since you're adding 10?

Comment: Change "_since pointer arithmetic on void pointers is undefined_" to "_since objects of type void have no size_".

Comment: Or rather, void pointers are pointers to incomplete object type, and pointer arithmetic shall only occur on pointers to a complete object type. Anything else is a constraint violation.

Answer (score 0):

These requirements don't make any sense. Tasks like these should be handled by the system-specific linker script and not the program.

What you would have in your linker file is a line allocating `addr1` at one specific address and `addr2` at another specific address. While doing so, you may find that these pointers are useless, as you'll have a chunk of memory allocated at a fixed address and from there you only need to know offsets.

Thus the solution to this "XY problem" is to have an array `uint8_t array[N];` allocated at a fixed address, and then define various constants as offsets of this array.